# $\log^\star n$ is somewhat common in runtimes. Does the superroot ever make an appearance?

Tags: ds.algorithms, time-complexity, ds.data-structures

Many algorithms and data structures have iterated logarithms ($\log^\star n$) in their runtimes. This function is the discrete inverse of tetration, in that

$$\log_a^\star (a \uparrow \uparrow b) = b$$

There’s another inverse to tetration called the superroot, which satisfies this definition:

$$\sqrt[b]{a \uparrow \uparrow b}_S = a$$

I’ve never encountered this function in any context in algorithms or data structures. While the iterated logarithm naturally arises when, well, iterating logarithms, I don’t have any intuition for what the superroot does or where it would arise.

Does this function actually get used in the analysis of any algorithms or data structures?